# Get the name of a pipeline and its activities

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am building a pipeline in ADF and I must save in the database the name of the pipeline and the activities that are being used, how can I save this information in the database?

Answer (score 2):

You would get a better answer if you could be more specific on when/where you want to do that, i.e the usage scenario. Without that, my best-guess answer is that you can use PowerShell to obtain that information.

Specifically, you can use the cmdlet `Get-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline`, as specified here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/get-azdatafactoryv2pipeline?view=azps-5.8.0

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, however I am new in this world, how can I use this command?

Comment: There is a fair learning curve if you are really new. Some starting points you may need to familiarise yourself with:

- PowerShell
- Azure PowerShell
- Az.DataFactory PowerShell module
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a python script to parse these details and then load it into the database this can all be done using Azure DevOps pipelines.